# how do i change font style of any website on Android browser without rooting?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, fonts

I want to know how can I change the font style of the webpage on any browser, it may be chrome, Mozilla, opera, or any other without rooting in android phone.

Comment: you must the application "font Changer" of the google play store or change the option on settings of your phone

Comment: Seems like any methods would be browser-specific. At least on Firefox, you can use extensions to do this. Chrome doesn't have extensions AFAIK, but you could (for example) use it to download Firefox (/me runs). But on a serious note: This seems overly ambitious (and overly broad for a question) to do for all browsers, especially without root.